# SQLite Query Exception Android Studio Syntax Error code 1

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

So im trying to build a search method for my android app and i keep running into this error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Prefect": syntax error (code 1): 
while compiling: SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = Ford Prefect
```

This is the method i have that is running the query

```
public Cursor findUser(String uName)
{
    Cursor res = myDatabase.query("Person WHERE name = "+uName+"",
                                         null,null,null,null,null,null);

    return res;
}
```

And the String uName comes from this method

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    EditText uNameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String userName=uNameField.getText().toString();

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button:
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(FindUser.this,
                    Results.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("uName", userName);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            break;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help with my im getting this error?? everything seems to be fine i just cant understand why it stops on the surname.  But the usernames are correctly formatted like so "Ford Prefect"

Comment: You need quotes around strings: `....  WHERE name = 'Ford Prefect'`. BTW use Prepared Statements - they handle that for you.

Comment: I havent came across those before, but looking briefly would it be something along these lines....
`SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE uName = ?");
stmt.bindString(1, "userName");
stmt.execute();`

Comment: Yes, it would be exactly that

Answer (score 1):

There should be single quote while passing the values .i.e., your query should be passed in this way "***SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = 'Ford Prefect';***". Below I have edited your question.

```
public Cursor findUser(String uName) {
    Cursor res = myDatabase.query("Person WHERE name = '"+uName+"';",
                                         null,null,null,null,null,null);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: With those amendments i now get this error
`android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`

Comment: @facesmie:: Before iterating the cursor. you had to include two if conditions `if(cursor != null) { if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {}`. Have you done this?

Comment: Ahh, so place my actions with that if statement to prevent outofbounds exceptions

Comment: @facesmie:: That if condition has to be validated in the area, where you parse the cursor.